Convex function for $x \to \infty$
Let $f(x)$ be a convex and monotone increasing function on the positive real line. Then for large enough $x$,$$\ln(x) \leq f(x).$$
Firstly observe $\ln(x)$ is concave, so $f(x) - \ln(x) = g(x)$ is convex. Assume $g$ is constant, then $f(x) = \ln(x) + C$ and the result holds.
So I need to show, for a non constant convex function $g(x)$, we have for large enough $x$ that $g(x) \geq 0$.
Assume $g(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$. Then, for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ $$g \, (tx + (1-t)y) \leq t \, g(x) + (1-t) \, g(y) < 0.$$
How could I go on? (It is not an exercise, just used in a part of a theorem).

How can this proof be correct? You could replace $\log$ by any concave function. That's all you use about log.

It is true, however, if you replace "convex" by "strictly convex". That is, if $f$ is strictly convex and $g$ is concave, then there is a $M>0$ such that $g(x)\le f(x)$ for $x\ge M$.

It is true if $f$ is not constant: Assume that $a < b$ with $f(a) < f(b)$. Let $L$ be the linear function with $L(a) = f(a)$ and $L(b) = f(b)$. Then $f(x) \ge L(x)$ for $x > b$ because $f$ is convex. But $L(x)/\ln(x) \to +\infty$ for $x \to \infty$, since $L(x) = mx+b$ with some strictly positive slope $m > 0$.
It follows that $f(x)/\ln(x) \to \infty$, and in particular $f(x)  > \ln (x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

thanks, I think I can live with the assumption f is not constant.

The statement is not true.
Consider $f(x)=1$, $f''(x)=0$ implies $f(x)$ is convex. For any $x\leq y, f(x)=f(y)=1$, so $f$ is monotone increasing. But $\ln x\leq 1$ is only true for $0<x\leq e$.

You can think about it like this:
Since $\ln x$ is strictly increasing, and diverges to infinity as $x\to\infty$, so it is unbounded by any constants. Thus a good counter-example is just constant functions (and they satisfies the requirements).

Yep, thanks, a completely correct answer. However, I think it sufficient to say f is non constant.
